# Dovecot and script execution - permission denied for a system command

Tags: bash, dovecot, shell-scripting, sieve

I have a shell script which is looking for a mailbox path

```
result=`find /var/mailboxes -type d -name me@my-domain.com`
perl -pi -e 's/Folder-to-Remove//g' $result/subscriptions
```

but executing it via Dovecot Sieve I'm getting an error message:

> lmtp: Error: find: `/var/mailboxes/63': Permission
>   denied

where `/var/mailboxes/63` is not even owned by `me@my-domain.com`

Shell script has permission to execute by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the Unix user that is used to execute the script, does not have permissions to access `/var/mailboxes/63` directory / file.

You need to find out some solution so that the directory / file permissions / ownership is set up so that the Dovecot Sieve user can access it. One has to keep security issues in mind.

In order to give a more complete answer, I need to see the ownership and permissions of the file / directory and the Unix user and the user's group used to run the Sieve script.

Comment: But `/var/mailboxes/63` is not right result for that find command anyway. When I execute that script via bash I'm getting correct path.

Comment: The `find` command searches through all files in `/var/mailboxes`, and the error occurs because it cannot access `/var/mailboxes/63`.

Comment: OK, got it. Is there any way to tell `find` to skip that mbox?

Comment: `find` has quite powerful methods for searching, I think there might be an option to exclude directories from search. However, I don't know exactly what the option is.

Comment: Use -type d -name what_I_want_to_exclude -prune